# Design Best Practices - Question Answer Comment Forms

Tags: design, question-answer

I am working on a Q/A type of web app. Below is how an answer looks like in my system.

[image]

Have a couple of queries

- Should the comment section have Avatar and the "Admin" title ?
- What can be done to make this even more user friendly
- Can some one point out bad design in this.

Would be of great help. Thanks

Comment: Looks pretty fine to me. What does the #6 stand for?

Comment: #6 is a permalink to the answer also says this is the 6th answer.

Comment: might want to make the comment containing the answer a little clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments look quite prominent in this design.  That is fine if you want to emphasize discussion around the answer, but if the answer itself is supposed to be the main point of the site, I would make the comments smaller and highlight them less--perhaps removing the gray highlight or nesting it inside the answer.

If you want to de-emphasize the comments, I suggest removing the avatar from them.  Admin probably conveys useful information, so I would leave it there, but it can be less prominent in the comments (perhaps not such a bold color).

Comment: what are your tots on the size of the comment box ?

Comment: @Yasser, make it more compact if you want to de-emphasize the comments.